# Why is Maven downloading a dependency from a different Nexus repo than ones specified in settings.xml?

Tags: maven, jboss, jenkins, jboss7.x, nexus

What am I doing incorrectly to handle this problem with JBoss's Nexus repositories?

I am trying to build JBoss AS7 and proxying the JBoss Public repository group via an internal Nexus repo.  I want the entire build proxied via my Nexus repo - no hitting of jboss.org Nexus repos.  However, I have encountered a problem.

Everything build OK until it is time to test jboss-as-jmx as it wants to download an artifact from an additional repo ... the /developer group.

I noticed in the log it attempts this:

```
Downloading artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jmx:jar:7.1.2.Final from jboss-developer (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/, releases+snapshots)
```

So I added jboss-developer repo id to my Nexus pointing to http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer and have added it to my proxied JBoss Public group.  However, it did not seem to override the jboss-developer repo and Maven still tries to download the artifact from jboss.org

Here is the log output of the test stage in question:

```
T E S T S
-
Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins/jobs/JBoss AS7/workspace/jmx" &amp;&amp; /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/bin/java -Duser.region=US -Duser.language=en -jar '/opt/jenkins/jobs/JBoss AS7/workspace/jmx/target/surefire/surefirebooter6443418663635953999.jar' '/opt/jenkins/jobs/JBoss AS7/workspace/jmx/target/surefire/surefire6887873281987795093tmp' '/opt/jenkins/jobs/JBoss AS7/workspace/jmx/target/surefire/surefire5481790486559149986tmp'
Running org.jboss.as.jmx.model.LegacyTypeConverterUnitTestCase
Tests run: 49, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.389 sec
Running org.jboss.as.jmx.model.ExpressionTypeConverterUnitTestCase
Tests run: 46, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.143 sec
Running org.jboss.as.jmx.model.NameConverterUnitTestCase
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running org.jboss.as.jmx.model.ObjectNameAddressUtilTestCase
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jboss.as.jmx.JMXSubsystemTestCase
Resolving artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jmx:jar:7.1.2.Final
Downloading artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jmx:jar:7.1.2.Final from jboss-developer (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/, releases+snapshots)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jmx/7.1.2.Final/jboss-as-jmx-7.1.2.Final.jar

org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jmx:jar:7.1.2.Final from/to jboss-developer (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/): Error transferring file: Connection timed out from http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jmx/7.1.2.Final/jboss-as-jmx-7.1.2.Final.jar
```

Here is my local ~/.m2/settings.xml - all other dependency artifacts have been proxied by this until this stage.  It still doesn't override Maven's attempt to download from http://repository.jboss.org for this one dependency, jboss-as-jmx.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://repository.mycompany.com:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <url>http://jbosspublic</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-developer</id>
          <url>http://jbosspublicdev</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <url>http://jbosspublic</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>jboss-developer</id>
          <url>http://jbosspublic</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Update 1:

When I run mvn help:effective-pom I see this fragment

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-releases-repository</id>
      <name>JBoss Releases Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>jboss-snapshots-repository</id>
      <name>JBoss Snapshots Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

and this one:

```
<jboss.releases.repo.url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</jboss.releases.repo.url>
<jboss.snapshots.repo.url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</jboss.snapshots.repo.url>
```

Which is odd because I know that all the other artifacts are downloading OK from my internal nexus proxy repo.  What I'll try next is adding those s to my /.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Do you have the JBoss repository configured in your `pom.xml` too?

Comment: It could also be in any of the dependency pom.xml files too. Can you see the jboss-as-jmx file from a browser on your machine at the nexus repo URL?

Comment: I've had removed the JBoss repository from the base module pom.xml.  Actually tried various things like URL replacement and such to no avail.

Comment: Additionally, please see the updated question.  I think the problem does lie with a transitive dependency somewhere or the JBoss Parent POM that is proxied via my Nexus repo to JBoss.org.  I have looked at the jmx module pom.xml and there appears to be nothing pointing to repository.jboss.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dependencies are downloaded as they are not part of maven build but part of testsuite.
where testsuite dynamically loads maven dependencies of previous version of components so it can tests the compatibility with previous versions.

take a look at [source code](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/model-test/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/model/test/MavenUtil.java#L179) on how/where this is done

Comment: Thanks.  I will play around will edit the source to point to my Nexus proxy, which will use http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/developer